# How do I turn off smart quotes in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, kramdown

How do I turn off smart quotes and apostrophes in Jekyll? It is breaking my gulp spellcheck process.

I want words like `doesn't` to stay with a single straight quote. Instead Jekyll is converting them to smart quotes like `doesnt’` and I need them to stay single quoted for spell checking.

This is what I tried in my _config.yml:

```
kramdown:
    smartquotes:  ["apos", "rsquo", "ldquo", "rdquo"]
```

I'm using kramdown.

Here is my whole config:

```
name: Bitcoin Bulls
markdown: kramdown
timezone: America/Detroit
highlighter: pygments
author: David Smith
safe: true
lsi: false
permalink: none

url: http://www.bitcoinbulls.net
exclude:  [CNAME, Gemfile, Gemfile.lock, '*.less', gruntfile.js, custom_css, node_modules, README.md, '*.svg', '*.docx']
include: [glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg]


kramdown:
    smart_quotes: ["rdquo", "rsquo", "ldquo", "rdquo"]


relative_permalinks: false

defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "" # empty string for all files
    values:
      layout: "default"
  -
    scope:
      path: "" # empty string for all files
      type: post
    values:
      layout: "post"
      is_post: true
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want this? Single and double tick marks (', ") are not apostrophes or quotation marks, they indicate things like feet & inches, minutes & seconds, etc.

Comment: @Rick the spell checking solution I used flagged everything with smart quotes as misspelled :(

Comment: That’s frustrating!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The underscore in `smart_quotes` is missing and the second array item needs to be `apos` to completely turn off smart-quotes for apostrophes.

```
kramdown:
    smart_quotes:  ["apos", "apos", "ldquo", "rdquo"]
```

To turn off smart-quotes for both apostrophes/single-quotes and double quotes, use this:

```
kramdown:
    smart_quotes: ["apos", "apos", "quot", "quot"]
```

That's what is know as the "Programmer's world compliant config".

---

More details:

By default kramdown transforms *apos* and *quot* into typographic quotes. That is:

- 'apostrophe' becomes ‘apostrophe’
- "quote" becomes “quote”

The default config provides guidance:

```
kramdown:

  # smart_quotes: 
  #
  #   first parameter : how an opening apostrophe is transformed
  #                     or apostrophe like in "I'm"
  #           default : ' -> ‘ (lsquo)
  #              apos : ' -> '
  #
  #   second parameter : how a closing apostrophe is transformed
  #           default : ' -> ’ (rsquo)
  #              apos : ' -> '
  #
  #   third parameter : how an opening double quote is transformed
  #           default : " -> “ (ldquo)
  #              quot : " -> "
  #
  #   fourth parameter : how a closing double quote is transformed
  #           default : " -> ” (rdquo)
  #              quot : " -> "
  #
  #   Default kramdown config
  #     smart_quotes: ["lsquo", "rsquo", "ldquo", "rdquo"]
  # 
  #   Programmer's world compliant config :
  #     smart_quotes: ["apos", "apos", "quot", "quot"]
```

Where:

- quot  = " : neutral quotation mark
- apos  = ' : apostrophe like in I'm
- lsquo = ‘ : typographic opening single quotation mark
- rsquo = ’ : typographic closing single quotation mark
- ldquo = “ : typographic opening double quotation mark
- rdquo = ” : typographic closing double quotation mark

[Kramdown's documentation](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/rdoc/Kramdown/Options.html) provides other options that may be of interest. The [Wikipedia Quotation Mark page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Typewriters_and_early_computers) provides lots of details on the complications of interpretation and how things changed when Unicode was introduced.

Comment: at time of this comment, the above linked kramdown docs says the default is `["lsquo", "rsquo", "ldquo", "rdquo"]`.